# AVG and Count from one columns

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I Have a table by this Columns :

```
[Student_ID],[Class_ID],[Techer_ID],[Course_ID],[Marks]
```

and for range of marks exist name for example:
    between 0 to 5 = D
    between 6 to 10 = C
    between 11 to 15 = B
    between 16 to 20 = A

Now i need create T-Sq l Query for Return this result message columns:

```
Teacher_ID|Course_ID|Count(Marks)|Count(A)| Count(B)|Count(C)|Count(D)
```

Very thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the same approach as Andomar, only change sum to count like this:

```
select  Teacher_ID
,       Course_ID
,       count(*)
,       count(case when Marks between 16 and 20 then 1 end) as countA
,       count(case when Marks between 11 and 15 then 1 end) as countB
,       count(case when Marks between 6 and 10 then 1 end) as countC
,       count(case when Marks between 0 and 5 then 1 end) as countD
from    YourTable
group by
        Teacher_ID
,       Course_ID
```

In my opinion, the query looks more natural this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  Teacher_ID
,       Course_ID
,       count(*)
,       sum(case when Marks between 16 and 20 then 1 end) as SumA
,       sum(case when Marks between 11 and 15 then 1 end) as SumB
,       sum(case when Marks between 6 and 10 then 1 end) as SumC
,       sum(case when Marks between 0 and 5 then 1 end) as SumD
from    YourTable
group by
        Teacher_ID
,       Course_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with PIVOT. (Note also that this formulation of the Marks-to-Letter calculation is a bit safer than one where both ends of each range must be typed.)

```
with T as (
  select
    Teacher_ID,
    Course_ID,
    case
     when Marks <= 5 then 'countD'
     when Marks <= 10 then 'countC'
     when Marks <= 15 then 'countB'
    else 'countA' end as Letter
  from T
)
  select
    Teacher_ID,
    Course_ID,
    countD+countC+countB+countA as countMarks,
    countA,
    countB,
    countC,
    countD
  from T pivot (
    count(Letter) for Letter in ([countA],[countB],[countC],[countD])
  ) as P
```